# Declarative Formik forms with MUI

Tags: material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I would like to use formik with [MUI](https://mui.com/). There doesn't seem to be a clear path to do this, the documentation does not make sense and the examples are nonsensical with compared to the docs.

For example. [This page](https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui) is at the top level of formik's examples. It is the only example that I can find on formik's site where MUI is integrated.

- The example uses the hooks method. There doesn't seem to be an example of the component method
- The example imports the button and the text field from the core material UI package. However, in this sandbox, components are imported from @mui/material and form formik-mui. Why two different package? Why isn't this covered in the docs?

All I want to do is build a formik form with mui styling and I can't find any docs for that.

For example, if I want to use a MUI text field, there are [online examples](https://morioh.com/p/cebbc2a3f459) that suggest using this method. However, once again I cannot find this in the docs and there is no explanation as to what is happening here or how I apply any props to this text field.

```
    <Form>
      <Field
        type="email"
        name="email"
        component={TextField}
        color={"error"}
      />
```

What am I missing here? I just want to build declarative formik forms with MUI.

Answer (score 1):

MuI and Formik are well documented, the only issue is the connection part is missing in both documentations.

For declarative formik you should switch from hook to render prop.

```
<Formik
    //
    initialValues={{ email: '' } as FormValues}
    onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
>
    {(formik: FormikProps<FormValues>) => (
        <Form>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

To clear a little bit your confusion with the connection part.
Mui don't use Formik so you must code an all form fields the connection to formik yourself.

```
<TextField
    name="email"
    label="Email"
    value={formik.values.email}
    onChange={formik.handleChange}
    error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
    helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
/>
```

For those repetative work it exists these neat library formik-mui.
If you use the library, it's just the following template left.

> Attention: The TextField comes from formik-mui

```
import { TextField } from 'formik-mui';

<Field
    component={TextField}
    name="email"
    label="Email"
/>
```